# Conservation of energy in a multiverse

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, multiverse

When I was studying about classical mechanics, I learned about Hamiltonian mechanics. In a example problem, we saw that in a system of just one capacitor, energy seemed to flow in and out and the conservation of energy law was violated. This was because in the example, the entire electrical circuit was not taken into account, which flowed energy in and out of the capacitor system. Therefore, I thought, if the universe was part of a [multiverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse), wouldn't a similar situation happen? Wouldn't the conservation of energy law not apply in our universe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most multiverse theories the worlds are effectively separated. Also, our particular world seems to be one that may well have a total mass/energy of zero.

Comment: I must have lost my total mass/energy meter yesterday because today I find it utterly impossible to get out of the universe to measure its total mass/energy. ;-)

Comment: Then just sum everything you can see and draw a conclusion

Comment: Then you have drawn an empty conclusion which you can't verify as being physically relevant. I do understand the temptation to pretend that everything is just the sum of its parts because that assumption works well enough often enough. However, when it works it does so because the basic rules of the game (like energy conservation) are the same. Unfortunately we already know that even the assumptions necessary for energy conservations are broken by the universe as a whole ($t_{cosmological} is not translation invariant). This leaves us with the question what smaller set of assumptions is valid.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-energy_universe

Comment: That's exactly the empty kind of conclusion I was talking about. Please note that these kinds of suggestions are emerging out of a great frustration of theoreticians who can't seem to bridge the gap between a purely phenomenological model that works quite well (standard model of particle physics) and the next level of microscopic theory. That frustration is not intellectual (these guys are not doubting their smarts), it's based on the missing observational data that could drive the next level of theory but is simply not available.